# wireless randomly becoming phantom hardblocked, only fixed by reboot

Tags: wireless, 14.04, broadcom, asus, rfkill

First off, I am aware of other people recently posting similar issues but none of the many fixes or suggestions in any thread I've seen has resolved the issue for me.

my ASUS netbook had been working fine for since I got it 6 - 8 months ago but in the past week or so the wifi started randomly freezing/crashing for no discernible reason and none of the normal methods for attempting to fix it yielded any results - only rebooting resolved it.

The first & most obvious method I tried was to restart network-manager, but when I did that I noticed that afterwards wifi showed up as disabled. Further research showed that somehow wifi had gotten hard blocked. There IS a button on the keyboard for wifi and at first I figured I had accidentally hit it but 1) hitting it again does not unblock wifi and 2) ever since I have been hyper-conscious of not hitting it and wifi still randomly gets blocked.

Sometimes I can use the internet for hours and hours with no issue and sometimes after wifi freezes/crashes it will freeze/crash again within minutes of rebooting. It has been at least a week of this happening at least once a day and try as I might I have been unable to figure out any guess as to what is causing or triggering the freezes/crashes.

Fixes I have tried that have not solved the problem:

-restoring BIOS back to defaults
-all manner of rfkill unblocking
-reinstalling wifi drivers
-switching from network-manager to wicd
-unloading & reloading wifi module (brcmsmac)

notably, brcmsmac does not reload once I have sudo modprobe -r 'd it, running sudo modprobe brcmsmac after that yields nothing and at that point running lshw shows the wireless adaptor as "unclaimed." Again, only a reboot fixes this.

other info/details:

The fact that this began within the past week or so seems to me to indicate some kind of update triggered this, but I've been running 14.04 since it was released in April so it would have to have been a more recent, smaller / more minor update that caused this issue if I'm correct in assuming that is what caused it.

```
lspci -vv

02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
Subsystem: AzureWave Device 2047
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
Region 0: Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

ifconfig

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d0:2b:71:7d:3f  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:36944 (36.9 KB)  TX bytes:36944 (36.9 KB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr dc:85:de:56:a4:14  
      inet addr:192.168.1.111  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::de85:deff:fe56:a414/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8442 errors:0 dropped:710 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:5874 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:5259231 (5.2 MB)  TX bytes:1242666 (1.2 MB)
```

rfkill list (when working)

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

lshw -C network (when working)

```
*-network               
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
   resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7d03fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eth1
   version: 10
   serial: 74:d0:2b:71:7d:3f
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:45 memory:f7c00000-f7c3ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: wlan1
   serial: dc:85:de:56:a4:14
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.13.0-32-generic firmware=610.812 ip=192.168.1.111 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

rfkill list (after crashed/frozen):

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

lshw -C network (after crashed/frozen)

```
*-network               
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: cap_list
   configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
   resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7d03fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eth1
   version: 10
   serial: 74:d0:2b:71:7d:3f
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:45 memory:f7c00000-f7c3ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
*-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: wlan1
   serial: dc:85:de:56:a4:14
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.13.0-32-generic firmware=610.812 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

results after running:  sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac && sudo modprobe brcmsmac (or any command variation of deactivating & then reactivating or modprobing brcmsmac)

```
rfkill list
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

basically phy0 dissappears, I'm assuming due to brcmsmac refusing to reactivate

```
lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f7d00000-f7d03fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eth1
   version: 10
   serial: 74:d0:2b:71:7d:3f
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:45 memory:f7c00000-f7c3ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
```

basically wireless adaptor shows up as "UNCLAIMED" again I assume related to brcmsmac not reactivating

EDIT

here are a few snippets that appear to be a relevant from /var/log/syslog as requested in comments:

```
Jul 28 02:20:04 chibitachop wpa_supplicant[1174]: wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Jul 28 02:42:32 chibitachop kernel: [29767.677589] brcmsmac bcma0:0: START: tid 1 is not agg'able
Jul 28 02:50:49 chibitachop kernel: [30265.344485] brcmsmac bcma0:0: START: tid 1 is not agg'able
Jul 28 03:05:34 chibitachop kernel: [31149.541093] brcmsmac bcma0:0: START: tid 2 is not agg'able
Jul 28 03:08:35 chibitachop kernel: [31331.008431] brcmsmac bcma0:0: START: tid 2 is not agg'able

Jul 28 17:20:55 chibitachop kernel: [82469.075694] brcmsmac bcma0:0: wl0: brcms_c_watchdog: dead chip
Jul 28 17:20:55 chibitachop kernel: [82469.144339] brcmsmac bcma0:0: ops->tx called while down
Jul 28 17:20:55 chibitachop kernel: [82469.332841] brcmsmac bcma0:0: ops->tx called while down

Jul 28 17:20:56 chibitachop wpa_supplicant[1174]: wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=bc:ee:7b:f3:32:b8 reason=4 locally_generated=1
Jul 28 17:20:56 chibitachop kernel: [82470.179674] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
Jul 28 17:20:56 chibitachop kernel: [82470.179688] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
Jul 28 17:20:56 chibitachop kernel: [82470.179692] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
Jul 28 17:20:56 chibitachop kernel: [82470.179697] brcmsmac bcma0:0: wl0: brcms_c_wme_setparams : no-clock
```

additionally in regards to the other posting this has been marked potentially redundant with, that user has 14e4:432b while mine is 14e4:4727 so the blacklisting procedure is different even if it did work, which as I said in my comment it did not for me.

searching based on error messages found in /var/log/syslog I found this thread from a couple months ago where someone using the same 14e4:4727 Broadcomm as me had similar problems which were never solved: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2212368&page=4

In response to the post my issue is currently allegedly a duplicate of, which itself redirects to a Broadcomm driver installation guide - that Broadcom installation guide was one of the first posts I found when I began researching this issue. According to that guide my Broadcom card is "Special Case #1 - This device uses the driver combination bcma and brcmsmac. It shouldn't be necessary to install anything at all. Required firmware is installed by default in the package linux-firmware." Despite that, I tried reinstalling the drivers and trying every combination of blacklisting all to no avail as mentioned in my original posting.

As I have said before, my wireless had been working fine for 6 - 8 months since I bought the computer so I know I had the driver configuration right until something somehow messed it up a week or so ago. My only guess as to what could have caused this issue is a change in a recent minor update since I hadn't made any adjustments to any wireless or networking settings since I initially set-up the computer back when I bought it and have been running 14.04 since it was released in April. Nevertheless as I already said one of the first fixes I tried before even posting here was reinstalling / blacklisting drivers as per the very instructions my post is currently marked as a duplicate of and it did NOT resolve the issue.

Comment: Boot the 14.04 installer ISO and "Try Ubuntu" to see if you can reproduce this in the original release. If you can not then it is probably a bug that got introduced with an upgrade. Do you see any errors in /var/log/syslog? Might be [bug #1287827 - 
wifi not configurable in network-manager showing disabled by hardware switch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1287827) _"Network manager shows Wifi is disabled by hardware switch. It worked just after install but not anymore after."_ - matches your report?

Comment: /var/log/syslog seems to have a lot of this going on: [31331.008431] brcmsmac bcma0:0: START: tid 2 is not agg'able not sure what that means beyond confirming brcmsmac is the problem.  bug #1287827 appears to be a network-manager bug solved by switching to wicd which did not solve my problem. The Broadcomm BCM4313 post was solved by reinstalling / blacklisting drivers which I've also already done and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this command in the terminal CTRL+ALT+T:

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
```

Reboot and wifi should work.

You may have to toggle your fn keys to remove the hard block after rebooting.

Here is the [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558) with full details by varun and chili555.

Comment: I had never seen this fix before so I tried it last night but unfortunately it has been crashing/freezing again today as usual so this didn't work either

Comment: @Chili555 : care to have a look?  Someone needs a guru...